# Unit testing a void method that returns a value using pytest

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, testing, pytest

For example, how could I go about unit testing the following method?

```
def list_append():
    data = []
    for file in files_list:
        with open(file) as f:
            data.append(json.load(f))
    return data
```

From my knowledge, there's no way to individually test the values of a local variable in a method, but please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: What local variable are you talking about? `f`? In that case, you want to mock `open` so that you control what gets bound to `f` in the first place.

Comment: `files_list` *isn't* a local variable; it's a free variable whose value you can change by direct assignment before calling `list_append`. (Though this strongly suggests that `files_list` should be an *parameter* of the function instead.)

Comment: I was actually talking about ```data```. I'll look into mocking. Also, you're right, ```files_list``` is a global variable, so might be better if I introduce it as a parameter instead.

Comment: You don't need to mock `data` or examine its value *during* the test. You call the function, and check that its return value is what you expect, given an appropriate "input" (i.e., value of `files_list` and the associated content of those files).